# Sandboxing a process in Openshift

Tags: linux, security, openshift, sandbox, paas

I'm currently writing a Web app where I'll have to run untrusted code from the user. I want to ensure that this code can't perform any network or disk io, other than using stdin and stdout.

I'm hopefully going to be using Openshift as my platform to deploy my application. From what I've read, it doesn't give me root access, since it's not a full OS virtualization.

Is there a way to sandbox a process, restricting its disk and network access, using the permissions I'd have on an Openshift gear?

Comment: Have you considered kernel namespaces?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this. Do you have a link?

Comment: Sure. This 7-part article is excellent: http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/.  From your question, you're probably most interested in the mount and network namespaces.

Comment: We actually already use namespaces, cgroups, and selinux to limit your application's access. The settings for that are not controllable by the application developer.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think to do this on OpenShift online is to use the REST api to spin up a container for the user, put their code in it, run it, and then delete the container once the user is done.

You don't have permissions as an administrator on the instance.